# Htaccess Rewriterule virtual directories breaking all links

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I think I've gone through a million articles and everyone's codes on this, but I just can't get it to work! Every code I try works but it shows the redirect url instead of the virtual one.

I would like mysite.com/company/client/ to actually show the results from mysite.com/company/client.php, but the files within client.php become broken unless I make absolute links.

For instance mysite.com/company/css/style.css is broken when viewing from http://mysite/company/client/, but is working fine when going to the real file mysite.com/company/client.php

I hope someone knows how to solve this problem without having to change all links in client.php to absolute!

Thanks!

Scott

Comment: Please provide some code from your .htaccess file. Show us some of your code from the actual page the links are breaking on as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider the HTML BASE tag:

```
...
<head>
...
<base href="http://mysite/company" />
...
</head>
...
```

You put this in the client.php file, then any relative link & reference is automatically "converted" to an absolute one, starting from the right folder.

---

See the comments on possible issues with the BASE tag.
Another option would be to perform a redirect instead of a rewrite, by adding "[R]" to the RewriteRule. However, then your users will see the "client.php" in the URL.

Comment: It is highly advised not to use the `<base>` tag if other options are available due to caveats it introduces. For example, the `<base>` tag will break all hyperlinks pointing to anchors (`<a href="#anchor"></a>`). Since his behavior is being caused because of a rewrite rule, there will be a way to address it via the .htaccess file. **EDIT**: This question actually has some good information on the `<base>` tag's problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag

Comment: The base does look like a good start! It seems to fix everything! Thanks very much for your replies. Yes I hope that there can be a solution that will work 100% of the time, for now I will use base.

Comment: @scott Edit your question to include samples of your code so we can try to assist you further.

Comment: @michael-irogoyen, there isn't really anything to show because I dont have a working htaccess statement; I'm just looking for that way in which I can make that client/ virtual folder show the contents of client.php without ruining the links. What I have right now in my htaccess is `code`
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.php$ http://mysite.com/company/$1 [R=301,L]`code`